# When not to use volatile，it still can see the changes which issued by other thread

Tags: java, jvm

```java
public class VisibleDemo {

    private boolean flag;

    public VisibleDemo setFlag(boolean flag) {
        this.flag = flag;
        return this;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        VisibleDemo t = new VisibleDemo();

        new Thread(()->{
            long l = System.currentTimeMillis();
            while (true) {
                if (System.currentTimeMillis() - l > 600) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            t.setFlag(true);
        }).start();

        new Thread(()->{
            long l = System.currentTimeMillis();
            while (true) {
                if (System.currentTimeMillis() - l > 500) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            while (!t.flag) {
//                if (System.currentTimeMillis() - l > 598) {
//
//                }
            }
            System.out.println("end");
        }).start();
    }
}
```

if it does not have the following codes, it will not show "end".

```java
                if (System.currentTimeMillis() - l > 598) {

                }
```

if it has these codes, it will probably show "end". Sometimes it does not show.

1. when is less than 598 or not have these codes, like use 550, it will not show "end".
2. when is 598, it will probably show "end"
3. when is greater than 598, it will show "end" every time

notes:

- 598 is on my computer, May be your computer is another number.
- the flag is not with volatile, why can know the newest value.

First: I want to know Why?

Second: I need help,

I want to know the scenarios: when the worker cache of jvm thread will refresh to/from main memory.

OS: windows 10

java: jdk8u231

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is suffering from a data-race and that is why it is behaving unreliably.

The JMM is defined in terms of the happens-before relation. So if you have 2 actions A and B, and A happens-before B, then B should see A and everything before A. It is very important to understand that [happens-before doesn't imply happening-before](https://preshing.com/20130702/the-happens-before-relation/) (so ordering based on physical time) and vice versa.

The 'flag' field is accessed concurrently; one thread is reading it while another thread is writing it. In JMM terms this is called conflicting access.

Conflicting accesses are fine as long as it is done using some form of synchronization because the synchronization will induce happens-before edges. But since the 'flag' accesses are plain loads/stores, there is no synchronization, and as a consequence, there will not be a happens-before edge to order the load and the store. A conflicting access, that isn't ordered by a happens-before edge, is called a data-race and that is the problem you are suffering from.

When there is a data-race; funny things can happen but it will not lead to undefined behavior like is possible under C++ (undefined behavior can effectively lead to any possible outcome including crashes and super weird behavior). So load still needs to see a value that is written and can't see a value coming out of thin air.

If we look at your code:

```
while (!t.flag) {
   ...
}
```

Because the flag field isn't updated within the loop and is just a plain load, the compiler is allowed to optimize this code to:

```
if(!t.flag){
     while(true){...}
}
```

This particular optimization is called loop hoisting (or loop invariant code motion).

So this explains why the loop doesn't need to complete.

Why does it complete when you access the System.currentTimeMillis? Because you got lucky; apparently this prevents the JIT from applying the above optimization. But keep in mind that System.currentTimeMillis doesn't have any formal synchronization semantics and therefore doesn't induce happens-before edges.

How to fix your code?

The simplest way to fix your code would be to make 'flag' volatile or access both the read/write from a synchronized block. If you want to go really hardcore: use VarHandle get/set opaque. Officially it is still a data-race because opaque doesn't indice happens-before edges, but it will prevent the compiler to optimize out the load/store. It is a benign data race. The primary advantage is slightly better performance because it doesn't prevent the reordering of surrounding loads/stores.

> I want to know the scenarios: when the worker cache of jvm thread will refresh to/from main memory.

This is a fallacy. Caches on modern CPUs are always coherent; this is taken care of by the cache coherence protocol like MESI. Writing to main memory for every volatile read/write would be extremely slow. For more information see the following [excellent post.](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/close-encounters-of-jmm-kind/#myth-reorderings-and-commit) If you want to know more about cache coherence and memory ordering, please check this excellent [book](https://www.morganclaypool.com/doi/10.2200/S00962ED2V01Y201910CAC049) which you can download for free.

Comment: Thanks!

But you still don't explain why 600 can end , and 550 will not end?

Answer (score -1):

> I want to know the scenarios: when the worker cache of jvm thread will refresh to/from main memory.

When Taylor Swift is playing on your music player, it'll be 598, unless it's tuesday, then it'll be 599.

No, really. It's that arbitrary. The JVM spec gives the JVM the right to come up with any old number for any reason if your code isn't properly guarded.

The problem is JVM diversity. There is a crazy combinatorial explosion:

- There are about 8 OSes give or take.
- There are like 20 different 'chip lines', with different pipelining behaviour.
- These chips can be in various mitigating modes to mitigate against attacks like Spectre. Let's call it 3.
- There are about 8 different major JVM vendors.
- These come in ~10 or so different versions (java 8, java 9, java 10, java 11, etc).

That gives us about 384000 different combinations.

The point of the JMM (Java Memory Model) is to remove the handcuffs from a JVM implementation. A JVM implementation is looking for this optimal case:

- It wants the freedom to use the various tricks that CPUs use to run code as fast as possible. For example, it wants the freedom to be capable of 're-ordering' (given `a(); b()`, to run b() first, and a() later. Which is okay, if a and b are utterly independent and are not in any way looking at each others modifications). The reason it wants to do this is because CPUs are pipelines: Even processing a single instruction is in fact a chain of many separate steps, and the 'parse the instruction' step can get cracking on parsing another instruction *the very moment* it is done, even if that instruction is still being processed by the rest of the pipe. In fact, the CPU could have 4 separate 'instruction parser units' and they can be parsing 4 instructions in parallel. This is *NOT* the kind of parallelism that multiple cores do: This is a single core that will parse 4 consecutive instructions in parallel because parsing instructions is slightly slower than running them. For example. But that's just intel chips of the Z-whatever line. That's the point. If the memory model of the java specification indicates that a JVM simply can't use this stuff then that would mean JVMs on that particular intel chip run slow as molasses. We don't want that.
- Nevertheless, the memory model rules can't be so preferential to giving the JVM the right to re-order and do all sorts of crazy things that it becomes impossible to write reliable code for JVMs. Imagine the java lang spec says that the JVM can re-order any 2 instructions in one method at any time even if these 2 instructions are touching the same field. That'd be great for JVM engineers, they can go nuts with optimizing code on the fly to re-order it optimally. But it would impossible to write java code.

So, a balance has been struck. This balance takes the following form:

- The JMM gives you specific rules - these rules take the form of: "If you do X, then the JVM guarantees Y".
- But that is all. In particular, there is **nothing** written about what happens if you do *not* do X. All you know is, that then Y is *not* guaranteed. But 'not guaranteed' does *not* mean: Will definitely NOT happen.

Here is an example:

```
class Data {
  static int a = 0;
  static int b = 0;
}

class Thread1 extends Thread {
  public void run() {
    Data.a = 5;
    Data.b = 10;
  }
}

class Thread2 extends Thread {
  public void run() {
    int a = Data.a;
    int b = Data.b;
    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(b);
  }
}

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Thread1().start();
    new Thread2().start();
  }
}
```

This code:

- Makes 2 fields, which start out at 0 and 0.
- Runs one thread that first sets `a` to 5 and then sets `b` to 10.
- Starts a second thread that reads these 2 fields into local vars and then prints these.

The JVM spec says that it is valid for a JVM to:

- Print 0/0
- Print 5/0
- Print 0/10
- Print 5/10

But it would *not* be legal for a JVM to e.g. print '20/20', or '10/5'.

Let's zoom in on the 0/10 case because that is utterly bizarre - how could a JVM possibly do that? Well, reordering!

**WILL** a JVM print 0/10? On some combinations of JVM vender and version+Architecture+OS+phase of the moon, YES IT WILL. On most, no it won't. Ever. Still, imagine you wrote this code, you rely on 0/10 NEVER occurring, and you test the heck out of your code, and you verify that indeed, even running the test a million times, it never happens. You ship it to the production server and it runs fine for a week and then just as you are giving the demo to the really important potential customer, all heck breaks loose: Your app is broken, as from time to time the 0/10 case does occur.

You file a bug with your JVM vendor. And they close it as 'intended behaviour - wontfix'. **That will really happen**, because that really is the intended behaviour. _*If you write code that relies on a thing being true that is NOT guaranteed by the JMM, then YOU wrote a bug, *even if* on your particular hardware on this particular day it is completely impossible for you to make this bug occur right now*.

This means one simple and very nasty conclusion is the only correct one: **You cannot test this stuff**.

So, if you adhere to the rule that if there are no tests then you can't know if you code works, guess what? **You cannot ever know if your code is fine**. Ever.

That then leads to the conclusion that you don't want to write any such code.

This sounds crazy (how can you simply not ever, ever write anything multicore?) but it's not as nuts as you think. This only comes up if 2 threads are dependent on ordering relative to each other for some in-process action. For example, if two threads are both accessing the same field of the same instance. Simply... don't do that.

It's easier than you think: If all 'communication' between threads goes via the database and you know how to use transactions in databases, voila. Or you use a message bus service like RabbitMQ.

If for some job you really must write multithread code where the threads interact with each other, don't shoot the messenger: It is NOT POSSIBLE to test that you did it right. So write it *very* carefully.

A second conclusion is that the JMM doesn't explain how things work or what happens. It merely says: *IF* you follow these rules, I guarantee you that THIS will happen. If you don't follow these rules, anything can happen. A JVM is free to do all sorts of crazy shenanigans, and this documentation nor any other documentation will ever enumerate all the crazy things that could happen. After all, there are at least 38400 different combinations and it's crazy to attempt to document all 38400!

So, what are the core rules?

The core rules are so-called happens-before relationships. The basic rule is simply this:

- There are various ways to establish H-B relationships. Such a relationship is always between 2 lines of code. 2 lines of code might be unrelated, H-B wise. Or, the rules state that line A 'happens-before' line B.
- If and only if the rules state this, then it will be impossible to observe a state of the universe (the values of all fields of all instances in the entire JVM) at line B as it was before line A ran.

That's it. For example, if line A 'happens before' line B, but line B does not attempt to witness any field change A made, then the JVM is *still* free to reorder and have B run before A. The point is that this shouldn't matter - you're not observing, so why does it matter?

We can 'fix' our weird 0/0/5/10 issue by setting up H-B: If the 'grab the static field values and save them to local a/b vars' code happens-after thread1's setting of it, then we can be sure that the code will always print 5/10 and the JMM guarantees means a JVM that doesn't print that is broken.

H-B are also transitive (if HB(A, B) is true, and HB(B, C) is true, then HB(A, C) is also true).

How do you set up HB?

- If line B would run after line A as per the usual understanding of how things run, and both are being run by the same thread, HB(A, B). This is obvious: If you just write `x(); y();`, then y cannot observe state as it was *before* x ran.
- HB(`thread.start()`, X) where X is the very first line in the started thread.
- HB(EndS, StartS), where EndS is the exiting of a synchronized block on object ref Z, and StartS is another thread entering a synchronized block (on ref Z as well) later.
- HB(V, V) where V is 'accessing volatile variable Z', but it is hard to know which way the HB goes with volatiles.

There are a few more exotic ways. There's also a separate HB relationship for constructors and final variables that they initialize, but generally this one is real easy to understand (once a constructor returns, whatever final fields it initialized are definitely set and cannot be observed to not be set, even if otherwise no actual HB relationship has been established. This applies only to `final` fields).

This explains why you observe weird values. This also explains why your question of 'I want to know when a JVM thread will refresh to/from main memory' is not answerable: Because the java memory model spec and the java virtual machine spec intentionally and specifically **make no promises** on how that works. One JVM can work one way, another JVM can do it completely differently.

The reason I started off making a seeming joke about playing Taylor Swift is: A CPU has cores, and the cores are limited. A modern computer, especially a desktop, is doing thousands of things at once, and will therefore be rotating apps through cores all the time. Whether a field update is 'flushed out' to main memory (NOTE: THAT IS DANGEROUS THINKING - THE DOCS DO NOT ACTUALLY ENFORCE THAT JVMS CAN BE UNDERSTOOD IN THOSE TERMS!) might depend on whether it gets rotated out of a core or not. And that in turn might depend on your music player dealing with a particular compressed music file that takes a few more cores to decompress the next block so that it can be queued up in the audio buffer.

Hence, and this is no joke, the song you are playing on your music player can in fact change the number you get. Hence, why you have to give up: You CANNOT enumerate 'if my computer is in this state, then this code will always produce Y number'. There are billions of states you'd have to enumerate. Impossible.

Comment: "No, really. It's that arbitrary. The JVM spec gives the JVM the right to come up with any old number for any reason if your code isn't properly guarded." This is not completely correct. The JVM doesn't allow for out of thin air values. So in case of a data race, a value needs to be seen that is actually written. There is one caveat and that is with a double or a long value. On a 32 bit platform where you could see a value made up by the first 32 bits of one write and the second 32 bits of a different write.

Comment: "The reason it wants to do this is because CPUs are pipelines" Pure pipelining isn't the cause of out-of-order execution. CPUs can execute instructions out of order due dynamic scheduling (Tomasulo algorithm) so an instruction can be executed as soon as its input dependencies are ready. Apart from that, the memory subsystem can make loads and stores appear out of order.

Comment: "There are various ways to establish H-B relationships. Such a relationship is always between 2 lines of code. " The happens-before relation is between 'actions' which can be plain loads/stores, synchronization actions (e.g. volatile load/store or lock acquire/release), external actions and thread divergence actions.